# Protobuf java create a Descriptor from DescriptorProto

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto

I was looking for a way to create from a `com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos.DescriptorProto` a `com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.Descriptor`

Like doing:

```java
var descProto = DescriptorProtos.DescriptorProto.newBuilder()
            .setName("MyDynamicType")
            .addField(DescriptorProtos.FieldDescriptorProto.newBuilder()
                .setName("my_dynamic_field")
                .setType(DescriptorProtos.FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TYPE_STRING)
            )
            .build()
Descriptors.Descriptor descriptor = theResponseToThisQuestion(descProto)
```

P.S. I'm start to thinking that it is not possible, as this function would be the protobuf compiler itself, and it is built to output .java files, so cannot be called at runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that message descriptors often depend on other messages, possibly defined in other files. So the top-level entry point for the library is [`FileDescriptor`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.FileDescriptor.html#buildFrom-com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto-com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor:A-) and [`FileDescriptorProto`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/ae26a81918fa9e16f64ac27b5a2fb2b110b7aa1b/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto#L62).

In the case where the message is self-contained (only primitive fields), it should be easy to just wrap the `DescriptorProto` using something like:

```
Descriptor standaloneMessage(DescriptorProto message) 
    throws DescriptorValidationException {
  FileDescriptorProto file = FileDescriptorProto.newBuilder()
      .setName("synthetic_file.proto")
      .addMessageType(message)
      .build();
  FileDescriptor file = FileDescriptor.buildFrom(file, new FileDescriptorProto[]{});
  return file.findMessageTypeByName(message.getName());
}
```

Comment: This might not behave exactly how you expect.  Any utility method that looks at the options of the file to understand how the message should behave likely won't work right.  For example, if you want to get the java package name, it will be incorrect.