# How to get Descriptor from a FileDescriptorProto

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have the following code

```
Descriptor descriptor = myProtoObject.getDescriptorForType();

FileDescriptorSet fileDescriptorSet = FileDescriptorSet.newBuilder()
        .addFile(descriptor.getFile().toProto())
        .build();
```

What I would like to know is how can I get back to Descriptor from FileDescriptorSet, so I can rebuild the dynamic message on the other side. .  perhaps like this

```
DynamicMessage.parseFrom(descriptor, myObjectBytes);
```

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667180/protobuf-java-create-a-descriptor-from-descriptorproto/68688421#68688421

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protobuf java create a Descriptor from DescriptorProto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667180/protobuf-java-create-a-descriptor-from-descriptorproto)